# Design question (use the same instance or copy?)

Tags: design

We are developing an e-learning website where you can practice LearnItems (typically words of a foreign language). The concept is very similar to Memrise.

When a user practices a LearnItem, a Result object is created (it contains the date of the answer, plus a flag to indicate if the answer given by the user was correct)

The LearnItems are grouped into LearnItemLists, and a user can choose to create his/her own LearnItemList, or use an existing one (e.g. LearnItemList "The 1000 most common english words", which has 1000 LearnItems)

This is where we have differing opinions in the team.
When a user wants to use an existing LearnItemList, created by someone else, then

**Version A:**

We store the same LearnItemList instance for every user that subscribed to the same LearnItemList.
This means that we have to store the results for each User+LearnItem in a separate structure, since a LearnItem belongs to several users.

**Version B:**

Deep copy all LearnItemLists.

We copy the LearnItemList with all its LearnItems to each user that subscribed. This way we can store the Results for the LearnItem for the given user simply by referencing User.LearnItemList.LearnItem.Results

Both versions have pros and cons, but in general, which one makes more sense?

Comment: Can users modify lists they subscribe to? Should they receive updates? Would an update merge with local modifications? Can users modify custom lists created by someone else? Would such modifications be visible to the original author? Answering these use cases may help you make a decision.

Comment: How are you persisting these LearnItems?  In a database?  Not knowing anything else about your application (or the questions that @axl just asked), I prefer that the *answers* be in a different table, and that you refer to the LearnItems by LearnItemID and UserID in the answers.  Why?  Because that's how databases work.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: yes, they are stored in a database

Comment: @axl: These are the exact questions we are arguing about

Comment: Can a user practice the same `LearItemList` multiple times? If a user can take the same list multiple times, it can be advantageous to store the results separately.

Comment: @user1437649 it sounds like you may want to make some decisions on the feature set before you finalize a solution.

Comment: @user1437649: axl's point is important. Will the user who uses the lists from another user is able to change it according to their personal needs? and when the creator of the list changes the original one, will this user be notified and receive the updates? These questions will help you clarify whether you need a copy of the lists themselves or of the results only

Comment: To my mind, whether the lists are fixed is a critical point to consider if they are shared (irrespective of whether does the modification). For example, if user A answers LearnItem3 incorrectly/correctly and then LearnItem3 is modified (or deleted!) then, depending how you store the data, reports may be misleading or incorrect. There is a similar issue with breakpoints in code - if the line is modified (e.g. commented out) or deleted, should the breakpoint still point to a line which has no content? The next line with content? The line prior to it?

Comment: It all boils down to behaviors. Do LearnItem have identities or they are values? If two users are sharing the same LearnItem and one has to be edited (e.g. typo) what happens? If someone uses an existing list, what happens when the list gets modifed? What kind of behaviors are attached to a LearnItem and a LearnItemList business-wise.

Answer (score 1):

I would store single instances of learn items bit have learnItemLists per user.

Ie

```
LearnItem
{
    String Id
    ....
}

User
{
    LearnItemList[] LearnItemLists
}

LearnItemList
{
    UserId
    Name
    String[] LearnItemIds
}
```

The key thing for me is that the user can make their own lists and presumably edit them.

Therefor if I want to use an existing list I will need to make my own copy of it.

I dont need my own copies of the learnItems themselves though, just the Id, as these are the same for all users

Comment: If the lists are persistent data structures, there's no problem with users sharing the same list (since editing a list returns a new object, possibly sharing some of the data).